# Issue passing value to Bootstrap Modal

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-modal

I am facing an issue where the record ID is not being passed to the Bootstrap modal in a laravel project

Blade Table View

```
@foreach($Srequest as $r)
                    <tbody class = "text-center">
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#invoicepaymentModal" class = "addpayment btn btn-success btn-round" data-id="{{$r->id}}" ><i class ="fa fa-dollar"></i></button>
                        </td>
                        <td>{{$r->id}}</td>
                        <td>{{$r->memberrequest->last_name}}, {{$r->memberrequest->first_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$r->invoice_number}}</td>
                        <td>{{$r->overview}}</td>
                        <td>${{$r->invoice_total}}</td>
                        <td>${{$r->requestpayment->sum('amount')}}</td>
                        <td class = "font-weight-bold">${{$r->invoice_total - $r->requestpayment->sum('amount')}}</td>
                        <td>{{$r->notes}}</td>
                    </tbody>
                    @endforeach
```

Blade Modal view (same blade)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="invoicepaymentModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="NewRollLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="editmemberModal">Invoice Payment</h3>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                <p type="hidden" value=($Srequest as $r)></p>
            </button>
        </div>
        {!!Form::open(array('action' => ['SquadronAccountingController@payment'], 'method'=>'POST', 'class'=>'form-horizontal'))!!}
        <div class="modal-body">
           <h4>Payment for Request</h4>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label-control">Invoice Number"</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" id="idHolder">
                </div>
                    <label class="label-control">Payment Amount:</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount">
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-round" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-round">Save Changes</button>
        </div>
        {!!Form::close()!!}
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript in blade

```
@section ('scripts')


<script>
  $("#invoicepaymentModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(e){
   var getID = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
   $("idHolder").val(getID);
 });

</script>
@stop
```

The issue I am facing is that a null value is being passed to the controller which fails the DB insert.

I wish to grab the record ID from the table and add this as an input field into the DB insert.

Comment: try `$("#idHolder").val(getID);` in script code.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing `id` from here `data-id="{{$r->id}}"`? did you try to `dump($r)` in your blade template?

Comment: This displays correctly - <td>{{$r->id}}</td>. So is there a need to dump($r), not clear why I would need to complete this. I want to pass that value to the modal.

Comment: @JinalSomaiya This failed as well. So I believe the value is not being passed correctly . Hence why I also posted the HTML table as well. Thanks